# How to search for Files using GetFiles method (multiple criteria..)

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

The code below obviously searches a directory for Files that contain the word "FINAL" but what I'm wondering is can I add to its search criteria?  I have a Well_Name and Actual_Date strings that I would like to search for in the File names in addition to the "FINAL" word.  Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

```
DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo("C://DWGs");
var files = myDir.GetFiles("FINAL");

//Can I do something like this to add to my search criteria?
var files = myDir.GetFiles("FINAL" + 
                            drow["Well_Name"].ToString() + 
                            drow["Actual_Date"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var files = myDir.GetFileInfo()
                 .Where(f => f.FileName.Contains("FINAL") ||
                             f.FileName.Contains(drow["Well_Name"].ToString()) ||
                             f.FileName.Contains(drow["Actual_Date"]));
```

Since `GetFiles()` returns an Enumerable Collection of `FileInfo` you can just check all of the file names for the criteria that you want.

If you want to get really generic on this you could write a function that looks like this

```
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> addCriteria(IEnumerable<FileInfo> FileList,
                                         List<String> searchCriteria)
{ 
   var newFileList = FileList;
   foreach(String criteria in searchCriteria)
   {
       newFileList = newFileList.Where(f => f.FileName.Contains(criteria).AsQueryable();
   }
   return newFileList.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: @msarchet-  Will the GetFiles method I'm using above search subfolders in that directory as well?

Answer (score 1):

`GetFiles` method does not support multiple search criteria, but there is a simple way around this limitation. Run a getFile for each file extension, and then "merge" returned arrays into a `List<>`. Then use a List's ToArray method to "convert" a List back to an Array.
I used this approach, and it works for me
The code is below (do not forget to reference "using System.Collections.Generic;" namespace):

```
// Get the DirectoryInfo and FileInfo objects for aspx and html files.
FileInfo[] files_aspx = dir.GetFiles("*.aspx");
FileInfo[] files_html = dir.GetFiles("*.html");

List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
files.AddRange(files_aspx);
files.AddRange(files_html);
files.ToArray();
```